# How can map contourf from matrix without inverse and draw lines?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, matrix, contourf

I would like to create a `contourf` plot from matrix 24x20 from dataframe like below scenario:

[image: img]

The snippet of my code is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3 , figsize=(20,10))
plt.subplot(131)
xlist = np.linspace(0, 20, 20)
ylist = np.linspace(0, 24, 24)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist)
plt.contourf(X, Y, df3, cmap="coolwarm" )
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.axis('off')
```

**Problem1** is I'm not sure why plot of `'A'` printed **inversely** and I have to use `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29906952/10452700) in order to invert it. I noticed that [In 7](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.04-density-and-contour-plots.html) is mentioned: `plt.imshow()` by default follows the standard image array definition where the origin is in the upper left, **not in the lower left as in most contour plots**. Is it the reason behind of that or am I doing something wrong?

**Problem2** I would like to divide matrix into 8 small ones by drawing 4 white lines but wasn't possible by using `ax.axvline(x=10, color='w',linewidth=1.5)`.
Based on [In 7](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.04-density-and-contour-plots.html) it seems likewise `plt.imshow()` doesn't accept an x and y grid, so it must manually specify the extent [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax] of the image on the plot. Is there any idea to accomplish that?

**Problem3** What's the benefit of **Interpolation** using `scipy.interpolate.griddata` or **Non-gridded contour** using `tricontour()` or this approach in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26088597/10452700) in my case?

**Problem4** when `interpolation='nearest'` is useful? I noticed the [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html) it's used for **finding contour**

**Note** The matrix which has 480 values is available in `.csv`file : [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t-29fz6l1w83PmLvYfPKZGB1uQhu1mWq/view?usp=sharing)

**Expected result** will be like bellow picture:
[image: img]

Comment: I'm a bit lost here on what the actual problem is (despite the nice graphics). So maybe you can split your problem into smaller parts. It might e.g. help here to look up and understand `numpy.meshgrid` and `numpy.reshape`. Come up with a toy example of some 12 value table, reshape the columns as 3x4 grid each and see if you can plot a contour of it; until then, don't worry about the rest.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Actually I followed your hints and made it simple and after I plotted it , I faced the few problems which I updated in question. I would like to hear from your side about them.

Comment: (1) Matplotlib y axes have extend vertically from the lower left corner towards the upper left corner. Hence, if you want to have the lowest value in the upper left corner, you need to invert the axis. This is different for imshow, but you don't have an imshow plot here. (2) `ax.axvline(x=10)` should work. Again, it's not clear what that has to do with an imshow plot, if a contourf plot is desired. (3) You have a rectilinear grid defined by the indices of your matrix. You do not have to interpolate anything.

Comment: (4) In that link the `imshow` is only used to plot the original data as a background to the contour plot. It is irrelevant for the contour finding.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for your short answer just regarding **Problem2**  when I use `ax = plt.contourf(X, Y, df3)` and then `ax.axvline(x=10)`  I get this error  `AttributeError:
'QuadContourSet' object has no attribute 'axhline'`

Comment: `ax` should be the axes, as in `fig, ax = plt.subplots(..)` If you later reassign something different to that variable `ax` it will not be the same any more.